# How can I find which keys in a Perl multi-level hash correspond to a given value?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a data structure which looks like this:

```
my %hoh = (
    'T431567' => {
        machin => '01',
        bidule => '02',
        truc   => '03',
    },
    'T123456' => {
        machin => '97',
        bidule => '99',
        truc   => '69',
    },
    'T444444' => {
        machin => '12',
        bidule => '64',
        truc   => '78',
    },
);
```

I want to search the various values of `truc` for a particular value and find the top-level attribute which corresponds to that entry. For example, looking for a value of `78`, I want to find the result `'T444444'`, because `$hoh{T444444}{truc}` is `78`.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might find that a different data structure, or even a simple database gives you a better way forward.

Comment: Please describe the size of your data structure, where the data has come from (reading a text file, a database, etc.) and how frequent you want to make a query like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `grep`:

```
my @keys = grep { $hoh{$_}{truc} == 78 } keys %hoh;
```

Note that this can return more than one key, if there are duplicate values in the hash. Also note that this is not particularly efficient, since it has to search the entire hash. In most cases it's probably fine, but if the hash can be very large and you may need to run lots of such queries against it, it may be more efficient to build a reverse index as suggested by Sobrique:

```
my %trucs;
foreach my $part (keys %hoh) {
    my $val = $hoh{$part}{truc};
    push @{ $trucs{$val} }, $part;
}
my @keys = @{ $trucs{78} };
```

or, more generally:

```
my %index;
foreach my $part (keys %hoh) {
    my %data = %{ $hoh{$part} };
    foreach my $key (keys %data) {
        my $val = $data{$key};
        push @{ $index{$key}{$val} }, $part;
    }
}
my @keys = @{ $index{truc}{78} };
```

Answer (score 4):

Can't with that data structure as is - There is no 'backwards' relationship from value to key without you creating it.

You've two options - run a search, or create an 'index'. Practically speaking, these are the same, just one saves the results.

```
my %index;
foreach my $key ( keys %hoh ) {
    my $truc = $hoh{$key}{'truc'};
    $index{$truc} = $key; 
}
```

Note - won't do anything clever if the 'truc' numbers are duplicated - it'll overwrite. (Handling this is left as an exercise to the reader).

Answer (score 2):

This solution is similar to those already posted, but it uses the `each` operator to process the  original hash in fewer lines of code, and probably more quickly.

I have added the dump output only so that you can see the form of the structure that is built.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hoh = (
  T123456 => { bidule => '99',  machin => '97',  truc => '69' },
  T431567 => { bidule => '02',  machin => '01',  truc => '03' },
  T444444 => { bidule => '64',  machin => '12',  truc => '78' },
);

my %trucs;

while ( my ($key, $val) = each %hoh ) {
  next unless defined( my $truc = $val->{truc} );
  push @{ $trucs{$truc} }, $key ;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%trucs;
print "\n";

print "$_\n" for @{ $trucs{78} };
```

**output**

```
{ "03" => ["T431567"], "69" => ["T123456"], "78" => ["T444444"] }

T444444
```

If you can *guarantee* that the answer is unique, i.e. that there is never more than one element of the original hash that has a given value for the `truc` entry, or you are interested only in the last one found, then you can write this still more neatly

```
my %trucs;

while ( my ($key, $val) = each %hoh ) {
  next unless defined( my $truc = $val->{truc} );
  $trucs{$truc} = $key ;
}

print $trucs{78}, "\n";
```

**output**

```
T444444
```

Simplest of all, if there is *always* a `truc` entry in each second-level hash, *and* its values is guaranteed to be unique, then this will do the job

```
my %trucs = map { $hoh{$_}{truc} => $_ } keys %hoh;

print $trucs{78}, "\n";
```

with the output as above.